# View Table does not allow NOT NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

So my query is

```
CREATE VIEW SourceTable 
AS 
    SELECT 
        CASE(
            WHEN a.answer = 'Yes' THEN 'Hoooray'
            WHEN a.answer = 'No' THEN 'Booo'
        END) as reaction
    FROM
        Source a;
```

The original column answer from table Source is declared to NOT NULL, but in view table (now called reaction column) it is still declared as NULL.

Why is this? How to make the reaction column to be declared as NOT NULL.

Tried changing the source column to NOT NULL but in view table it is still showed as NULL

Comment: if `answer` was neither 'Yes' nor 'No', the default result of CASE will be null... so you need to be sure you cover all cases or provide an ELSE (such as `ELSE ''`)

Comment: What's a "view table"? Also try putting an `ELSE 'Booo'` since `NULL` would be the result if `a.answer` is _any other value_. ([Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/Wj0DbPsd).) It's not enough that it can't be `NULL` to avoid the `CASE` expression from yielding `NULL`. Even if there is a check constraint restricting it to those two explicit values. (Maybe you should have used a bit column.)

Comment: And whats with the invalid brackets?

Comment: @Stuckat1337 add that as an answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try putting an `ELSE 'Booo'` (or any other string you like) since with your current expression `NULL` would be the result if `a.answer` is any other value than `Yes` or `No`.

```
CASE a.answer WHEN 'Yes' THEN 'Hoooray' 
              WHEN 'No'  THEN 'Booo' 
              ELSE 'Booo'
END as reaction
```

In fact if `Yes` and `No` are the only possible answers, you can simplify:

```
CASE a.answer WHEN 'Yes' THEN 'Hoooray' 
              ELSE 'Booo'
END as reaction
```

([Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/5j5fJVPH).)

It's not enough that the column can't be `NULL` to avoid the `CASE` expression you've written from yielding `NULL`. Even if there is a check constraint or `WHERE` clause restricting it to those two explicit values. If there isn't a possible non-`NULL` outcome for every branch (and `ELSE` is always a branch even if you don't explicitly include it and even if it would be impossible to reach), the outcome has to be considered nullable.

(In the future, I might suggest a `bit` column for things like `Yes`/`No`.)